# No-index a node

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm trying to no index 2 different nodes, I found the [Node noindex](http://drupal.org/project/node_noindex) module for it but I don't think it works. So I'm wondering if there is alternative to doing this.

Comment: It is correct that prior to April 5 2018, **Node noindex** did *not* work. However, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the [Node noindex](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_noindex) plugin make sure you check the content types and enable it there. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> ... makes it possible to include a noindex-header on specific nodes. This should ensure that the node does not get indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [NodeWords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) or [MetaTags](http://drupal.org/project/metatags) modules? Otherwise you can always handle it through the templating engine if you don't want to use a module.

Comment: i found it, they really need to post more direct paths for where to find this stuff in the modules, ill post the answer later

Answer (score 1):

**Option #1**: [Node Noindex Module](http://drupal.org/project/node_noindex)

This works and is pretty simple as answered by @Jeremy Love

**Option #2**: [Metatag Module](https://drupal.org/project/metatag)

Not immediately apparent and not simple, but it is powerful:

1. Enable Metatag and Metatag Context (you will need to enable Context and want Context UI)
2. Create a new context in Context UI with a Path condition of node/123 (the particular node ID)
3. Add a Meta data Reaction to that context to "prevent search engines from indexing this page" and a whole lot of others.